# Ajax form - image upload | access denied in ie

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, forms, ajaxform

I'm creating a facebook application, and want to implement an ajax-like picture upload using the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Everything is ok in chrome/ff but in iexplorer i get the folowing error:

```
Message: Access Denied   
Line: 349  
Char: 5  
Code: 0  
URI: http://application.my_domain.gr/apps/new_app/js/jquery.form.js
```

I am aware of the cross domain issues, but can't understand why this is happening, since all scripts i'm curently using are on the same domain.
Here's how i've done it working in firefox/chrome:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
        <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div>

<script>
$('#photoimg').bind('change', function() { 
                    $("#preview").html('');
                    $("#preview").html('<img src="img/loader.gif" alt="Upload in progress"/>');
                    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                                        target: '#preview',
                                        success:    function() { 
                                                $("#preview img").attr("id", "uploaded_img");
                                        }
                    }).submit();
                                        
            
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made some workarounds, still trying to remember them to post the solution. Please add the correct App Domain(s) in your app basic settings, and provide feedback.

Comment: How did you solve this one? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: I have a same problem in IE Please help.

Comment: The issue in my case was solved when i added my domain to App Domains in the app's basic settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's a while since I posted the question, but here's what finally worked for me:

I just added my domain to "App Domains" in the app's Basic Settings (Basic Info section) and everething worked ok!

Answer (score -1):

IE will shows error if you are doing an ajax call from a secure page (https)
to non secure page or vice ver.

Make sure all the urls, page url and ajax url are all with the same security.